# snowflake - how to use variables during create table with references

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wanted to set session level variables and tried the below for identifying database and schema names.
USE database and USE schema works with the set variables. But I get an error while referencing foreign key.

```
SET (DB_VAR, SCHEMA_VAR) = ('XYZ_DB','XYZ_SCHEMA');

USE DATABASE IDENTIFIER($DB_VAR);
USE SCHEMA IDENTIFIER($SCHEMA_VAR);


create or replace TABLE TEST_VAR
( 
    PARENT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL
    , CHILD_ID NUMBER
    , primary key (PARENT_ID)
    , foreign key (CHILD_ID) references IDENTIFIER($DB_VAR).IDENTIFIER($SCHEMA_VAR).ABC_TABLE(ID) 
);


create or replace view TEST_VAR AS SELECT * FROM IDENTIFIER($DB_VAR).IDENTIFIER($SCHEMA_VAR).TEST_VAR;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a string dynamically and execute it using the execute immediate command:

```
execute immediate
$$
declare s string default 'create or replace TABLE TEST_VAR' ||
    '(PARENT_ID NUMBER NOT NULL ' ||
    ', CHILD_ID NUMBER ' ||
    ', primary key (PARENT_ID) ' ||
    ', foreign key (CHILD_ID) references ' || $DB_VAR || '.' ||
    $SCHEMA_VAR || '.ABC_TABLE(ID))';
begin
    execute immediate s;
end;
$$
```

If you're using the Snowsight client you may not have to wrap the body of the anonymous block with `$$`. This may let you use $$ to define your string, so you don't have to worry about linebreaks.